# Reverse Triangle using stars

Tags: javascript

I am having to make a triangle and upside down triangle using asterisks for my class.

I have made the top half however, I am having a great deal of trouble making the upside down part

```
for(var count=1; count < 8; count++) {
    for(var count2=1; count2<=count; count2++) {
        document.write("*");
       }
    document.write("<br/>");
}
```

Whatever I try, it either does not print at all or prints the result of the above code.

Comment: Surely it's just `for( var count2=count; count2>=1; count2--)`? Of course there's better ways of doing it, and "cleverer" ones (`Array.from({length:count+1}).join("*")` for example)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I can only use things which we have done thus far.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're talking about this, when you say "upside down triangle"

```
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

If so, then using "just what you have done" so far, you can do it like

```
for(var i=0;i<8;i++){
   //for(var spaces=0;spaces<i;spaces++){
        //  document.write(" ");
   //}
   for(var ast=8;ast>i;ast--){
        document.write("*");
   }
   document.write("<br />");
}
```

Also added another loop, if you want "upside down with spaces"